# Passing data between java webservice and phonegap

Tags: java, cordova

Ok this is basically my objective. I have created a webservice in java which is connected to a mysql database using eclipse IDE. I want to pass data from this web service to my front end and from the front end back to the webservice. As I am using phonegap I basically have to pass data to javascript and then populate that in html. 
Can anyone give me some pointers ? A detailed explanation would be very helpful I am a newbie !!

I created a web service with a method check(String name)

```
public String attempt(String name)
    {   System.out.println(name);
        return name+" says hi ";
    }

My end point is http://localhost:8357/TestWS/services/check
```

I tried this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form(){
        var username=$("#name").val();
                var data = { name: username };
                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"http://localhost:1002/TestWS/services/check",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "json",
                    });  
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" id="name"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_form()"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It still doesn't seem to work :$

Comment: The simplest way is to use jQuery ajax request or javascript XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Use RESTful web services with Spring MVC.. easy

Comment: RESTful web services and Spring MVC is out of question because it is unavailable due to circumstances at work. 
Do you know of any tutorials for using jquery ajax with java webservice ?

Comment: Have you used jquery ajax call normally..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where you want to get/post web service data

**Get data from web service:**

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'Your web service url',
            type: "GET", // optional. because default is GET
            dataType: "json", // List object will come as json
            success: function(yourListObject) {
               // Here, process your list object as you wish
           }    
     });
```

**Post data to web service:**

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8357/TestWS/services/check',
                type: "POST",
                data: data, // no need to convert json object for string params
                success: function() {
                   alert(' Username has sent successfully');
               }    
         });
```

Comment: If I pass data as json objects to the web service dont I have to package data in json objects while passing from the java web service ? I'm very interested but havent been able to find any tutorials/examples

Comment: Edit your question according to below question. 1) what kind of data do you really want to get from web service? and 2) What kind of data do you really want to post to your service..? so that we can help you.

Comment: Here is a gist as you asked for, 
I want to pass form data, like a username and password to my web service basically two string values.
I also want to pass a java list object to my front end in phonegap

Comment: the data 'username=hai&password=hello' can be stored into an Object ? or is it a jsonString ?
say if my method is authenticate(),should my arguments be of type Object ? Or should it be of type jsonString which can be converted to java objects ?
Sorry if it is a stupid doubt but this is my first experience with json

Comment: I did but I don't think it is working since the console doesn't show the output of System.out.println(name);